# Populate all slot values in AWS lex for user selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am building Food Ordering System using AWS Lex.

I create a Slot Type with All Slot Values.

I added this slot to Intent.

I want to populate all the values from this Slot so that User can make selection.
But it is only populating prompt, not showing values.

[image]